# C++ - Copy string to char* does not work for HMAC-SHA1 in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl

Given a string "TEST", I want to convert it to an array of chars

```
 char goal[] = "TEST";
```

Here is how I copy the string to char*:

```
 char *test=new char[k.size()+1];
 test[k.size()]=0;
 memcpy(test,k.c_str(),k.size());
```

The method above actually works, or **it seems to work**.

Let's say I just have:

```
   char goal[] = "TEST";
```

then I debug my code using the GDB as follow:

```
 (gdb) b function
 (gdb) p goal
 $1 = "TEST"
```

However, when I use the code above to copy the string to char* the debugger outputs:

```
 (gdb) b function
 (gdb) p test
 $2 = 0x1001000d0 "TEST"
```

On printing, there's no change. They both print "TEST" (using cout or whatever).
However, this changes everything in my code:

```
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

function(string A, string B) 
{
    // The following two lines yield to correct solution: AFF791FA574D564C83F6456CC198CBD316949DC9
    char key[] = "Password";
    char data[] = "Message";

    /* Alternative yields to:  2b2c26033b2dcfc22051941c31bd3cf54f96816d
        string k = "Password";
        char *key=new char[k.size()+1];
        key[k.size()]=0;
        memcpy(key,k.c_str(),k.size());

        char *data=new char[d.size()+1];
        data[d.size()]=0;
        memcpy(data,d.c_str(),d.size());
     */

    unsigned char* result;
    unsigned int len = 20;

    result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

    HMAC_CTX ctx;
    ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
    ENGINE_register_all_complete();
    HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);
    // Using sha1 hash engine here.
    // You may use other hash engines. e.g EVP_md5(), EVP_sha224, EVP_sha512, etc
    HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, key, strlen(key), EVP_sha1(), NULL);
    HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&data, strlen(data));
    HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
    HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    // cout << key << " - " << data << endl;
    cout << "HMAC digest: " << endl;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != len; i++)
        printf("%02x", (unsigned int)result[i]);
}
```

Comment: since you're already mixing C++'s new and C's malloc, why not go all the C way and use strdup to clone your strings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&data, strlen(data));
                                  ^^^^^
```

When you declare `data` as an array, then - most likely - its address `&data` has the same pointer (numerical) value as the pointer which it would decay into if you didn't use the addressof (`&`) operator. Only the types of the two pointers differ (`char *` versus `char (*)[8]`).

(This is just an implementation detail, neither one of the C and C++ standards require this, but commonly it's implemented like so.)

If you, however, declare `data` as a pointer, then `data` and `&data` differ even more drastically - and `&data` is incorrect, you're hashing the **address stored in the pointer itself,** instead of the string it points to.

All in all, drop that `&`.

Comment: @crazyGuy I was having a hard time figuring this out in all that enormous wall of code you posted :P